# Agregar columna a una query SQL con valores

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Mi situación es la siguiente: estoy trabajando con el SQL Developer 19 y necesito hacer un select de una tabla de gabinetes, trayendo su nombre y su modelo. Hasta ahí voy bien. Me pidieron que a dicha consulta agregue una columna más que contenga el puerto según el modelo. El tema es que debería ser así: suponiendo que mi gabinete se llama FLV01-A02 y que su modelo es de 8 puertos, necesito que al realizar la consulta, me lo traiga de la siguiente manera

[image: ReporteFinal]

Es decir, traer el mismo registro 8 veces pero variando el puerto desde el 1 al 8. Y lo mismo para el modelo CTO16, que es de 16 puertos.
La realidad es que no tengo ni idea por dónde empezar, todo lo que tengo es esto, que lógicamente me imprime "port" en toda la columna que asigné como PORT:

```
SELECT DESCR, MODEL, port AS PORT FROM CABINET_LT WHERE DESCR LIKE '%FLV01-A02%';
```

¿Alguna idea? Desde ya muchas gracias.